# PhD first-year transfer including credits

Tags: phd, transfer-student

I'm currently in graduate school A as a first-year student. However, due to some personal reasons, I really want to go to another graduate school B, also as a PhD student.

I have been accepted by B now. The application portal I used is not specifically for transfer students though. So, is it possible for me to transfer my credits earned at A to B? And how should I begin this discussion with my current advisor that I'm leaving for non-academic reasons? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that "credits" are needed? Often the coursework in a doctoral program is just preparation for comps. The requirements of many programs are just "pass comps and write an acceptable dissertation". It would be moot in such a program.

Comment: Yes, transferring credits can reduce the number of courses I need to take at B. Thus, I can focus more on my research. That's why I want to transfer credits. Could you please elaborate it a little bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can add to this a bit more about credits if needed (as per my comment), but for your advisor, I'd just open with the fact that you need to change programs for non academic reasons and that you would be happy to discuss it with them. If they need more information then they will follow up. Otherwise there isn't really a need.

But it would be good to leave on good terms with them. As a first year student you probably don't have a deep relationship yet, so it may not matter, but anyone and everyone who has a good opinion of you can be an asset going forward in your career.